# IE7 & 8 hover state not working when using underscore template to populate html

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, backbone.js, underscore.js

Has anyone else had issues with IE hover states not working when using underscore template engine.
IE7 and 8 do not show hover states. If I remove the _.template() method and just put the html in directly instead of dynamically it all works.

here is my underscore template setup
I'm also using backbone to store my data that will update the template with, using this.model.toJSON()

```
var template= _.template( $("#mytemplate").html() );
this.el.html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ) );
```

UPDATE: 
I stripped this down and I have noticed that even if I don't use underscore and just use jquery `html()` method it also doesn't work. for example:

```
this.el.html( $("#mytemplate").html() );
```

here is my template code.

```
<script id="mytemplate" type="text/template">
    <div class="content">
    <a href="http://www.cnn.com">Testing Rollover</a>
    </div>
</script>
```

Has anyone else had this problem.

Comment: Yes, I had an issue with session cookies not being saved because of an underscore in the staging URL (slightly different I know but sounds familiar). I did some research and found out that IE does not play well with underscores, our solution was to omit underscores in the clients staging URL - you might want to consider a different option to using an underscore in this case too!

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I'm referring to underscore.js not _. Underscore.js is a template based engine. http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/

Comment: ha! my mistake, figured if it was regarding _ it might help to shed some light.

Answer (score 0):

ie8 doesn't play nicely with underscores; this should fix ie8
var template= *(*(.template( $("#mytemplate").html() ) ));

you can reference it here: https://gist.github.com/39ac06be6abc96c8a69e